# Eigenvalues of the product of a column vector times a row vector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $u^T = [1\cdots 1]$.

The matrix $A=uu^T$ has rank 1, and its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 0$ with multiplicity $n-1$, and $\lambda_2 = u^Tu = n$ with multiplicity $1$.

Is it true in general that the second eigenvalue (aside from zero) of a matrix that is the result of multiplying a column vector and a row vector is the scalar product of the two vectors? If so, why? If  not, what's the second eigenvalue (aside from zero) in general?

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ and $v$ are two vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (columns), then $u \times v^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Either it is the zero matrix and thus there is nothing much to say, either it isn't. As you said, if $u^Tv$ is not the zero matrix, it has rank $1$: this means that $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $(n-1)$.

Now, let $\lambda$ be its second eigenvalue (in $\mathbb{C}$). As the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, then:
$$
\lambda + (n-1)\times 0 = \mathrm{trace}(u\times  v^T) = \mathrm{trace}(v^T \times u) = v^T\times u= \langle v,u\rangle = \langle u ,v\rangle
$$
because whenever $A \in M_{n,m}$ and $B\in M_{m,n}$ we have $\mathrm{trace} (A\times B) = \mathrm{trace}(B\times A)$, and, moreover, $v^T\times u$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, thus, a scalar, and is equal to its trace. This shows that the last eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the scalar product of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the case $n=3$ which is enough for understanding what happens.

Let us have a look at what $UV^T$ (where $U,V$ are nonzero column vectors) looks like.

If the entries of $U$ and $V$ are resp. $a,b,c$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$:

$$M=UV^T=\begin{pmatrix}a\\
b\\c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta &\gamma \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a \alpha&a \beta&a \gamma\\
b \alpha&b \beta&b \gamma\\
c \alpha&c \beta&c \gamma\end{pmatrix}$$

meaning that the columns are all proportional to $$U=\begin{pmatrix}a\\
b\\
c\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the range of $M$ is the one-dimensional vector space generated by $U$. Otherwise said, $M$ is a rank-one matrix.

As a consequence of rank-nullity theorem, the kernel of $M$ has dimension $3-1=2$. Therefore, $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity 2 (for the general case with $n$ instead of $3$, $0$ will be an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$).

The unique non-zero value is obtained through the trace property:

$$\lambda + 0 + 0 = a\lambda+b \beta+c\gamma$$